# How can I make my game's FPS be virtually unaffected by a low priority background task?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, priority

I'm running a desktop system where I often have long-running compilation tasks in the background. I'd like to play CPU-limited games while they're running without a significant drop in FPS (the game only uses <4 of my 8 cores).

I set up a simple test scenario with two `stress -c $(nproc)` processes.

Nice doesn't really work anymore on modern Linux distros (and especially not in my actual use-case), so the best method of prioritising a task is using the SCHED_IDLE scheduling policy.

So I set one of them as SCHED_IDLE (and an inconsequential nice 1 for differentiation) and the other is running regularly with SCHED_OTHER.
As expected, CPU usage is `0.1 us,  0.1 sy, 99.8 ni,  0.0 id` when the emulated background task is running and `99.5 us,  0.2 sy,  0.3 ni,  0.0 id` when both are running.

However, this difference does not translate well to the game: Running the game normally with no background process results in 83 FPS, running it with a SCHED_OTHER background task results in highly variable 35 FPS and a SCHED_IDLE one in a fairly stable 60 FPS.

Why does the game's performance go down so much eventhough it could use nearly 100% of the available CPU resources if it needed to?
How could I get it closer to the <10% performance drop you'd expect from the boost frequency reduction and L3 cache congestion caused by activity on the previously idle cores?

(Without generally cripping compilation performance of course; I'd like that to be as fast as possible when I'm not doing anything else. `make -j1` would technically do it, I know.)

Comment: Some old Intel CPUs with an iGPU has had this perk for many years now. The bug is still open.

Comment: You could use `taskset` to run your game with some dedicated CPU cores, and also to run the shell you do your background compilations in with another set of dedicated cores.  Child processes inherit the CPU affinity of their parent.   Use another shell (not started with taskset) when you want to use all cores for compiling.    If you're running on a NUMA machine (e.g. an early model threadripper running in NUMA mode, like my 1950x), you can use `numactl` instead of `taskset` (I sometimes use this to run steam so that it only uses cores on the same NUMA node as my nvidia GPU).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not sure you replied to the correct question?

Comment: @cas as I mentioned in the question, generally crippling the compilation workload is not an option. It needs to be done dynamically by the scheduler. In this case, I can't even easily access the processes as they're run by the nix-daemon and it might go through multiple different builds in one "session".

Comment: As you've already discovered, the scheduler does not do what you want it to.  You'll have to discover other methods.  Setting CPU affinity via taskset or numactl is about the only other way available on Linux and does not "generally cripple compilation workload" - you can easily choose whether to compile with all CPU cores/threads or just a subset of them that aren't shared with a running game (because you've given different CPU affinities to those tasks).   Before dismissing it, I suggest you actually try it and base your opinions on data rather than assumptions.

Comment: this may mean having two startup scripts for your "nix-daemon" - one that allows all cores/threads to be used, and the other only allowing cores/threads that will not be used by a game.   Switch between them as required.  You could even wrap your games in scripts that automatically switched which "mode" nix-daemon was running in before starting a game and after exiting it.   Or write something to monitor whether a game is being played or not.   BTW, in some cases, just locking games to a fixed set of cores will be good enough - the scheduler will try to allocate other processes to other cores.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it does seem to do what I want it to. The simulated foreground task can "steal" almost 100% of the available CPU resources from the simulated background task. The problem is that this doesn't seem to translate to my game. With "generally cripple" I mean limiting the CPU resources the process has access to for its entire runtime; like `make -j1` in a traditional compilation job. For the third time though: This is not an option in my use-case. If it was, I'd be doing that already. Fixed CPU affinities are also not an option as the games are very dynamic.

Comment: The nix-daemon is not some custom script or anything, it's the Nix package manager's systemd service that manages builds and a few other things. It's not something I could trivially restart whenever I want as builds are often long-running (think hours). I can tweak it's CPU scheduling policy and any other systemd/cgroup setting for its entire runtime though.